# Emacs projectile with multiple repos (git/svn etc.) in one project

Tags: git, emacs, emacs-projectile

I have a single git repo with a directory structure that looks like this:

```
root ---------- src
        |
        |
        |------ 3rd
```

`root` is my working directory, `3rd` consists of multiple third-party git submodules.
`projectile-find-file` only finds files in `src`, it does not work for the submodules.

Comment: It seems you were able to solve the problem yourself which is great! However, instead of including the solution in your question, you might want to consider posting an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) below. (You will even be able to accept it after 48 hours.)

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for following up on my suggestion! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`projectile-git-command` uses `git ls-files` to list the files belonging to the project,
so I resolved the problem with the following code:

```
(setq projectile-git-command "git-ls-all-files")
```

`git-ls-all-files` is a shell script:

```
\#!/bin/zsh
files=`git ls-files -co --exclude-standard`
sb_files=`git --no-pager submodule --quiet foreach 'git ls-files --full-name -co --exclude-standard | sed s!^!$path/!'`
all_files=$files$sb_files

echo $all_files
```

Comment: Or, all in one command: (setq projectile-git-command "cat <(git ls-files -zco --exclude-standard) <(git --no-pager submodule --quiet foreach 'git ls-files --full-name -co --exclude-standard | sed s!^!$path/!')")

Comment: That's cool! Thanks you very much! And two git ls-files commands should use same flags `-zco`.

Answer (score 7):

I just had an equivalent problem, I fixed it by adding an empty `.projectile` file to my `root` directory, this tells projectile that that directory is the real project root and to search all the files in it's subdirectories when you want to find something.

See [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile#synopsis) for more info.

Comment: Thanks - this helped me solve a similar issues as OP. I needed a way to tell projectile to load multiple repositories (similar to "adding a folder" in VSCode) so that I could grep through and open files belonging to multiple repositories.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution of Mike, I add a `.projectile` file to each submodule and this submodule will become a new project in Emacs.